# Adding Firebase VAR to website

Tags: firebase, var

I setup and account at http://feedthefire.in and on Firebase dot com - to manage feeds I would liek to display on my site.  I set everything up and the feeds get pulled into Firebase just like it should, now its time to add it to a web page...nothing, can't get the feeds to pull in from Firebase.  I added the firebase.js reference in the header and in the body I placed

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ref = new Firebase"'https://aodf.firebaseio.com");
    ref.child("meta").once("value", function(snapshot) {
        $("#e-title").html(snapshot.val().description);
    });
    ref.child("articles").limit(3).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
        var article = snapshot.val();
        var link = $("<a>", {
            "href": article.link,
            "target": "_blank"
        });
        $("#e-list").append($("<li>").append(link.html(article.title)));
    });
```

when you go to http://sandbox.studiorooster.com/ao I should see a list of feeds, but I don't, so I know I am supposed to place something else in the code; I think :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of problems in what you posted above, each of which is explained below:

1. Syntax error on line #2: `var ref = new Firebase("https://aodf.firebaseio.com");`
2. You're loading a description on lines #3-5, but never rendering it, because there is no element with id `e-title` in the page you linked to. Trying adding `<h2 id="e-title"></h2>` to your template.
3. Similarly, you are loading a number of articles on lines #6-13, and trying to append each of these items to a list with id `e-list`, which also does not exist in your template. Try adding `<ul id="e-list"></ul>` to your template.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Rob.  I made the changes as suggested but it still doesn't pull anything in.  Any other ideas?  Than you again.

Comment: Looking at [http://sandbox.studiorooster.com/ao/](http://sandbox.studiorooster.com/ao/), you still have a syntax error here: `var ref = new Firebase"https://aodf.firebaseio.com");` should be `var ref = new Firebase("https://aodf.firebaseio.com");`.

Comment: I recommend reading [Google Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console) to learn about how to use browser tools to track down these issues.